# DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function handleUserPublished(_x5, _x6)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

**Suspected code :**

```
        <button
          id="join"
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
          disabled={joinState}
          onClick={() => {
            join(channel, authorize, null);
            history.push({                    <------------ Maybe here
                pathname: "/api/hole?holepk=1&live=true&channel="+ channel,
                state: {client: client,  joinState: joinState, localAudioTrack:localAudioTrack, remoteUsers: remoteUsers, authorize: authorize}
            })
            //setChannelList(channel);
          }}
        >
```

**Error**

```
DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function handleUserPublished(_x5, _x6) {
        return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
      } could not be cloned.
```

If I erase the **state** part, the error disappears, but I cannot deliver what I want.

What's the problem?

Comment: Add your `history` definition please and try to restart you app.

Comment: It has already been declared as follows.    

`const App = ({client, channelList, setChannelList, authorize, history}) => {`